# Использование Testcontainers без Spring

Tags: java, docker, юнит-тесты, junit

Всем привет! Начал разбираться с Docker и Testcontainers для домашки, где использование Spring запрещено. В проекте используется база данных - с ней происходят разные взаимодействия. Я развернул базу в докере, но не понимаю, как нужно писать тесты через Testcontainers. Например, как протестировать добавление данных в базу, или изменение в базе, или просто вывод из базы? Я подключил контейнер в тестовом классе через:

```
    private static final PostgreSQLContainer<?> container = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.2");
```

Но что делать дальше? Во всех примерах, роликах на ютубе и тд используется Spring...
Заранее спасибо!

*Ниже представляю примеры функций*

**Функция добавления**

```
    @Override
    public void addTransaction(TypeOfTransaction type, int amount) {
        String sql = """
                INSERT INTO entities."Transaction" (type, amount)
                VALUES (?, ?)
                """;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.open();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, String.valueOf(type));
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, amount);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Функция изменения**

```
    @Override
    public void minusBalance(String login, int amount) {
        String sql = """
                UPDATE entities."Client"
                SET balance = balance - ?
                WHERE login = ?
                """;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.open();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, amount);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, login);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

**Функция вывода**

```
    @Override
    public void printAudit(String login) {
        String sql = """
                SELECT action
                FROM "Client_Audit"
                WHERE client_login = ?
                """;
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.open();
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1, login);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("action"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для подключения к контейнеру нам необходимо получить строку соединения с базой развёрнутой в нем(аналогично с реальной) и после через DriverManager вернуть подключение. При этом при создании контейнера мы можем добавить скрипт создания базы.

Пример создания контейнера и поиска записи по id. Результатом возвращается DTO объект, которым мы потом проверяем через assertEquals входящую в Junit5

```
@Testcontainers
public class Test {
    static String dbName = "testDb";
    static String login = "test-user";
    static String pass = "123";
    static String schema = "CREATE TABLE test("
       + " id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL,"
       + " description TEXT);";

    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:15.2")
        .withDatabaseName(dbName)
        .withUsername(login)
        .withPassword(pass)
        .withInitScript(schema);

public Client getClientById(int id) {
    String sql = "SELECT id, name, description FROM test WHERE id = ?;";
    Client client = null;

    try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(), login, pass);
            PreparedStatement prStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        prStatement.setInt(1, id);
        prStatement.execute();

        ResultSet result = prStatement.getResultSet();
        if (result.next()) {
            client= new Client(result.getInt("id"), result.getString("name"), result.getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return client;
    }

    @Test
    void getById() {
        int id = 5;        
        Course course = new Course(id, "name", "description");
    
        Course actualCourse = getCourseById(id);
        assertEquals(actualCourse, course);
    }
}
```

Для полноценных тестов, результат работы ваших методов лучше переделать на возврат DTO объектов, которые уже потом выводить на экран в отдельном методе. Это упростит тестирование, а для перехвата возврата соединения можно использовать Mockito.

Пример возврата соединения:

```
void mockConnection() throws SQLException{
    lenient().when(Connection.getConnection()).thenReturn(DriverManager.getConnection(postgreSQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(), login, pass));
}
```